# When using the async='true' on my html script tag to load socket.io.js it cause an undefined error for the io object any suggestion?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, undefined

When adding  async='true' as an inline property to a html script tag to serve my socket.io.js file asynchronously it cause an undefined error for the io object when I try to connect to the server. I corrected this 90% of times by loading my socket.io first in the head tag and but loading the js file that connect last but I'd rather not loose 10% customers, anyone's got an idea of how to fix this? I've tried connecting after the document is loaded like just keep being undefined. The only way to ensure the socket will connect at 100% chances is to remove the async='true' inline property from my script tag. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is your main script inline or does it use a `src`?

Comment: It does use a src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to asynchronously load `socket.io`, you need to `defer` the scripts that depend on it and make sure they are located below the `socket.io` script in your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script async src="js/socket.io.js"></script>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script async defer src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Adding `defer` ensures that among the `<script>`s loaded asynchronously, it will execute in the order that it exists in the HTML. Of course, if `defer` is not supported, then neither will `async` be supported, so it will still load in the correct order, just the `socket.io.js` will block rendering until it is loaded.

Comment: You sir are very knowledgeable in the subject. Thank you very much.